# Why rpc-json error codes are negative integer?

Tags: json-rpc

As we can see from json-rpc [specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#error_object) error object has required member `code` that must be an integer.

But why for pre-defined errors there is reserved codes as negative integer?